# Apache Access Control Allow Origin issue for woff2 file type

Tags: apache, .htaccess, font-face, font-awesome

I m facing an access control origin issue while trying to load a font awesome font face. This is the error message logged in Chrome browser console.

```
Access to Font at 'https://example.com/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0' from origin 'https://example2.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://example2.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

And I have updated the apache2 server httpd.conf and enabled the headers.

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType application/font-woff2           .woff2
</IfModule>

  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff2|woff|font.css|css|js)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
  </FilesMatch>
```

and also I have try the same settings with the .htaccess file but the results was the same. It is bit weird, because I'm facing this issue only for **woff2** file extension.

Comment: Wrapping directives in `IfModule` always raises the question "is this module really enabled?". Without `IfModule` you will get at least some server error in the log files.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Yes the module was enabled. I really couldn't fixed it at the server side but the following trick fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to use a server script rather than a physical font file

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSans';
    src: url('path/to/fonts.php') format('woff2');
}
html, body{
    font: normal 16px OpenSans, sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

How to fix cross-domain @font-face issues with PHP

```
<?php
// fonts.php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/font-woff2");
echo @file_get_contents("path/fontawesome-webfont.woff2");
?>
```

[Reference](https://zinoui.com/blog/cross-domain-fonts)